# Breadcrumb overflow issue in Opencart

Tags: css

My product names are very long and they need to stay long.
When the breadcrumb shows the product page, if the screen is small (for example mobile view) the breadcrumb overflows the layout and it causes the browser not to show the page correctly.

I tried to add `<p class="overflow-ellipsis">` and also `<p class="overflow-visible">`to the `DIV` of the product page which did not work, I tried to add `text-overflow: ellipsis;` and also `text-overflow: visible;` to the css in breadcrumb section, which also did not work, I also changed the `white-space: nowrap;` in breadcrumb css to `white-space: normal;` and it still did not fix the issue.
Here is a link to one of my pages for example, please make the screen small or see in mobile to replicate the issue.

http://www.nativeamericanwholesale.com/$80-tag-authentic-made-by-charlene-little-navajo-kingman-turquoise-wrap-bracelet

I will need the product name to stay in layout (frame) and preferably goes to second line instead of overflowing the page.
Please note that I do not want to use hidden visibility or anything to cut it out due to SEO issues.

Comment: Share any image or code, we cannot assume this much :)

Comment: Provide some code to show what you want it to look like and why doesn't it work.
Also, have you tried `word-break: break-all;`  ?

Comment: @hunzaboy I just added link to replicate the issue.

Comment: @fen1x, I did use word-break: break-all; and it did not work either.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Set `white-space` for your breadcrumbs:

```
.breadcrumb > li {
    white-space: normal!important;
}
```

I used `!important` to override any other code for `.breadcrumb > li`, but you should know this is not a good practice.

Comment: It is in the question that I already did this and it did not change anything

Comment: How exactly did you add it? Bootstrap default code could have overriden it

Comment: I added the normal to the CSS

Comment: What exact code did you use? Did you add it before or after bootstrap.css? Did you try it with `!important`?

Comment: It's added to the stylesheet.css where is has all the breadcrumb CSS. I didn't add important, how should I add that ?? It's being added tit he existing CSS not a new CSS

Comment: Edited my answer

Comment: I also added it with important, it did not change either. I am getting a feeling that its being overwritten. But cannot figure out the issue. Checked all cache files in xml and modification.

Comment: Breadcrumb on your page is wrapping as expected, as i can see now

Answer (score 0):

I confirm white-space: normal (and white-space: break-all) isn't enough for OpenCart's breadcrumb issue.

```
.breadcrumb>li:after{top:50%;transform:translateY(-50%) rotate( -45deg );} 
.breadcrumb>li{white-space:normal;display:table-cell;vertical-align:middle;}
.breadcrumb>li:last-child::after{display:none;}
```

This will fix your issue.

[image]

Answer (score -1):

Add this thing to your class.

```
.breadcrumb li > a {
    white-space: normal;
}
```

Here you need to use `.breadcrumb li > a` because product name inside a tag in future if will add any other tag inside then li then it will affect to everywhere so better is to used .breadcrumb li > a.

Comment: I did the above, it is also explained in the question, it did not change anything

Comment: Are you talking about about this thing am i right?

https://nimbus.everhelper.me/client/notes/share/1013480/wd53y7z2vr4q91txrguk

Comment: That's exactly correct but it doesn't get fixed by changing the nowrap to normal in the CSS